# Flushing error when adding to url

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm creating a silverstripe project on localhost. My OS is linux which I'm just new from using.

After trying to flush my project by adding `?flush=1` at the end of the url, it gives me an error of

```
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in 
    /opt/lampp/htdocs/try/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php on line 357
```

which result not being able to run what I made.

please help

Comment: Please read this solution https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/518

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error on ?flush and /dev/build i backuped 2 .hraccess files and the error was gone. So what i did i executed these two commands from my project root.

```
mv public/assets/.protected/.htaccess public/assets/.protected/.htaccess.bck
mv public/assets/.htaccess public/assets/.htaccess.bck
```

Or do it manually - go to public/assets/.protected/ and rename .htaccess to .htaccess.bck and then go to public/assets/ and also rename .htaccess to .htaccess.bck
if you still get the error then rename files back to original name and keep looking for other broken .htaccess and rename them one by one and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score -1):

You are executing `chmhod` command from your file `Local.php`, the file needs the permission to execute this command.

You can give the permission to this file but make sure you give it the required permissions only. You can give 655 or 755 to make it work, again based on what you need to do.

You can give the permission to a file like this:

```
chmod 655 fileName.php
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, though I tried using this both 655 and 755 command 
sudo chmod -R 655/755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/try/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php
still didnt work

Comment: why do you use `chmod`? can I see that ?

Comment: Due to restriction of linux in creating a file in htdocs, I used sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ to add my project. my project still on localhost so I can't show it.

Comment: Not sure if `chmod 777` created this all issue, you don't need to give 777 to all files.

Comment: im just new to linux so I think I rushed things out

Comment: Still, eventhough i give chmod 777 to all files, this particular error should have been granted the permission. I dont know what happens